# Asp.net - Starting server with Kestrel on OS X

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I have not worked with Asp.net before. I'm trying to get an MVC Project running on my machine. I'm running OS X 10.9.3.

I tried following the instructions in this tutorial: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html

But when I run `$ dnx . kestrel` in the projects directory I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'XYZ' from /Users/jeff/Sites/XYZ/XYZ.com
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ApplicationHostContext..ctor (IServiceProvider serviceProvider, System.String projectDirectory, System.String packagesDirectory, System.String configuration, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName targetFramework, ICache cache, ICacheContextAccessor cacheContextAccessor, INamedCacheDependencyProvider namedCacheDependencyProvider, IAssemblyLoadContextFactory loadContextFactory, Boolean skipLockFileValidation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost.Initialize (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHostOptions options, IServiceProvider hostServices) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost..ctor (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHostOptions options, IServiceProvider hostServices) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at dnx.host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName targetFramework) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It means that dnx cannot find `Startup.cs` file. Try to run `dnx . kestrel` inside folder which contains `Startup.cs`